# How i can localize enums with EF Core IQueryable projection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, localization, asp.net-core-webapi, iqueryable

I have asp net Web Api. In get all method I use EF Core IQueryable to retrieve data from DB. Then use project to for map Domain class to response class. Then send this queryable in LoadAsync method from DevExtreme library to search/filter/pagination.

```
public override async Task HandleAsync(DataSourceLoadOptions req, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var feature = this.CreateFeature(_mapper, () => new GetReservationsQueryFeature());
    Result<IQueryable<Domain.Reservation>> result = await _mediator.SendRequestAsync(feature, ct);

    if (result.IsSuccess)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(feature.Language);
        var queryResult = await DataSourceLoader.LoadAsync(result.Payload.ProjectTo<GetReservationResponse>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider), req, ct);
        //do some localization
        await SendOkAsync(queryResult, cancellation: ct);
    }
    else
    {
        await this.SendIssueAsync(result.Issue, ct);
    }
}
```

This is my mapping Profile.

```
public class GetReservationMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public GetReservationMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Core.ReservationCore.Domain.Reservation, GetReservationResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Uid, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Uid))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            //...
    }
}
```

Now I need localize Status property based on cultureInfo. Status is enum property and I have .resx to localize this enum. How can I do it? Without any extra for/foreach loop on queryResult?

Thanks.

Comment: The property must not necessarily be enum. Maybe I want to translate a string property.

Comment: Do projection by yourself, via `Select` (without AM). If library do not help, you should not use it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yeap, without projection it works fine

Comment: What does your `enum` contain? Do you need to display all those or part of the result?